# How to identify the package manager used to install software in CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum, php, make

On my CentOS 7.2 Server:

```
[root@localhost data]# which php
/usr/local/bin/php
[root@localhost data]# ll /usr/local/bin/php
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 29 Jun 25 08:13 /usr/local/bin/php -> /usr/local/php-7.1.16/bin/php
```

There is a PHP is running on my CentOS 7.2, but how can I dpkg --status the package manager used to install PHP?  I mean whether it was installed using `yum` or a make installation?

Comment: Dear @fanhualuojin154873. Your question was flagged unclarity. I made edits to make it clear. Would you please confirm that the current revisions reflect the objective of the question? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run `rpm -qf /usr/local/php-7.1.16/bin/php`.

If it responds with:

```
file /usr/local/php-7.1.16/bin/php is not owned by any package
```

then you know for sure the file was not installed using any RPM package management tool.

As others have said, the fact that it is installed under `/usr/local` indicates it is definitely not installed from the distribution's standard packages. It might be installed using `make`, or it might be some third-party RPM.

The only way to (somewhat) positively confirm that the files were installed with `make` would be to find a PHP 7.1.16 source code tree on the system, with `.o` or other object code files present (= indicating that the source has actually been compiled) and their timestamps are close to the timestamps of the PHP binary in /usr/local/php-7.1.16/bin/php.

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be possible to answer that question.

First, use `yum` to check if the PHP binary belongs to an installed package: `yum whatprovides '*bin/php'`

If `yum` does not find the package, then most likely it was not installed via `yum`. I say most likely in the event yum's database is corrupted.

If it was not installed `via` yum, then it would not be possible to determine if it was installed via `make` because `make` doesn't typically leave any trace of its use; It copies the files to where they need to go, but doesn't leave a record of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `php` was installed via `make`.

First, in CentOS there aren't php7 binaries in the official repositories (there are php7 binaries in other repositories like 'Remi' or 'Webtatic'), second `/usr/local/` is, accordingly to the [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html):

> The `/usr/local` hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being overwritten when the system software is updated. It may be used for programs and data that are shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not found in `/usr`.

IMHO I think that your php was built locally with make.